# Next.js default 404 page is not shown for non-existing pages

Tags: next.js

I'm creating a next.js app.

And when I enter a non-existing URL, instead of seeing the default `404` page, I see this message:

> Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

And when I open the console, all I see is this line repeating:

```
on-demand-entries-client.js?4540:45  
 GET https://localhost:3000/non-existing-url 404    
eval    @   on-demand-entries-client.js?4540:45    
eval    @   websocket.js?f03c:39     
handleMessage   @   websocket.js?f03c:38
```

And here are the files in my `pages` directory. I have no custom `_error.js` page or `404.js` page:

[image]

I'm stuck as there is no information whatsoever to tell me what's wrong in the console, and I have not created custom error pages.

What should I do?

Comment: is there any specific reason you don't have a `_error.js` or `404.js` file? if it isn't in the folder you are always able to create them yourself.

Comment: No specific reason. I just don't need to create custom error pages. I'm OK with the default pages.

Comment: What Next.js version are you using? Can you provide a [mre]?